# Алгоритм определения конца предложения в текстах

Tags: java

Нужно разработать алгоритм определения конца предложения в текстах. В алгоритме учесть многообразие английского научного языка. Например, многоточие (а также !!!, ??? и прочее), сокращения, инициалы, точку как разделитель числа, прямую речь, отсутствие заглавных букв и прочее.

Написать программу, реализующую разработанный алгоритм.

Сам алгоритм представить в виде функции, возвращающей позицию конца предложения в тексте.

Comment: Это задание? Такие вопросы мы закрываем, идите на фриланс. Если вы предприняли шаги по реализации алгоритма, и вы наткнулись на проблемы в реализации(или вовсе не можете составить алгоритм), то отразите это в вопросе. Поможем, чем сможем.

Comment: regex , parsing ...

Comment: @Victor Это понятно, но Лана хочет, чтобы ей программу написали. Либо она забыла добавить свой код

Comment: Сейчас причину учебные задания отключили на месяц. Но за других никто писать не будет. Разве что маленькие программки :)

Comment: @Victor попытаюсь написать. Программа должна быть маленькой, строчки вспомню...

Comment: Попробуйте через регулярные выражения

Comment: Товарищи, это непростая задача. Попробуйте отличить конец предложения от сокращения типа `р. Днепр`. Наверняка в английском языке похожая ситуация есть.

Comment: ну как, я сделал

Comment: Оцените, ребят. Code rev там, где его не ждешь)

Answer (score 1):

Мое решение данной задачи:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class EnglishTextParser {
    static final char[] EXTRA_SYMBLES = new char[] {
        '.', '!', '?', ';'  
    };
    static final String[] WORD_ABBREVIATIONS = new String[] {
        "testAbbreviation"
    };

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] indexesOfExtraSymbles = getIndexesOfExtraSymbles("я не. но не. О... testAbbreviation. как же так?");
        for(int i : indexesOfExtraSymbles) { // вывод индексов с новой строки.
            System.out.println(i); 
        }
    }

    private static int[] getIndexesOfExtraSymbles(String text) {
        ArrayList<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int c = 0; c < text.length(); c++) {
            for(int e = 0; e < EXTRA_SYMBLES.length; e++) {
                if(text.charAt(c) == EXTRA_SYMBLES[e]) {
                    out:
                    for(int i = c - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        if(text.charAt(i) == ' ' || i == 0) { // можно сделать, конечно, статическую константу(массив) 
                            for(String abbrivation: WORD_ABBREVIATIONS) {
                                if(abbrivation.equals(text.substring(i + 1, c))) {
                                    break out;
                                }
                            }
                            indexes.add(c);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    out:
                    for(int c1 = c + 1; c1 < text.length(); c1++) {
                        for(int e1 = 0; e1 < EXTRA_SYMBLES.length; e1++) {
                            if(text.charAt(c1) == EXTRA_SYMBLES[e]) {
                                c++;
                            } else {
                                break out;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return convertIntegers(indexes);
    }
    public static int[] convertIntegers(List<Integer> integers){
        int[] ret = new int[integers.size()];
        for (int i=0; i < ret.length; i++)
        {
            ret[i] = integers.get(i).intValue();
        }
        return ret;
    }

}
```

Comment: В каком приложении запускать код? не получается у меня

Comment: Сейчас изменю ответ

Comment: В Eclipse создайте класс с названием EnglishTextParser. В него засуньте этот код, и нужный текст засуньте вместо тестовой строки в методе main

Comment: Чисто для интереса - вам это зачем?

Comment: p.s.: этот алгоритм учитывает только аббривиатуры. Мне было интересно - потому сделал. Если нужен полный алгоритм - идите на фриланс.